Land/tax records in USA—public vs. private
What public benefit (if any) is there in automated access to land and tax records by non-government entities?
My income tax records are private information and should be.  Privacy rules mean even I have to verify my identity to get to them.
And I can get online and at no charge, read or print all the info about the taxes on my property.  But no identification is required and anyone can get it.
But, since the taxes are not in default—paid on time and always have been—why should a SCAMMER three thousand miles away be able to offer me an “urgently needed” copy for $132.80?  Fine print acknowledges that the records are actually free, but I have no doubt that a lot of victims don't read the fine print.
The same $132 scam includes a copy of the deed.  The deeds are public and probably should be, but I see NO public benefit for this clown in Florida to be able to use automated means to be notified that I bought the property and send me this "offer" before I even make the first payment.  When the legitimate owner has to contact the county clerk and wait for him/her to find it in the files.  (With a reasonable labor charge of a mere $3.75.)

This sounds more like a rant than a question.

It's a question, followed by the background that prompted it.

Part of the question sounds like a legal but ethically dubious business scam. This is very special and maybe not really about politics. Maybe the part about businesses wanting to sell information that is freely available can be removed from the question?

"..and should be..." I agree but interestingly enough, opinions on that seem to differ and there are countries that make this information public. I would therefore remove it, it's not necessary for the question.

+1.  Yes, maybe it's a bit argumentative, but it does raise good questions about why to open/not open certain data and the tradeoffs of data governance.  Look at the number of upvotes on the answer, along with the (perhaps under-sourced) gem of In general, privacy laws almost always lead to more fraud, not less fraud.  Concentrate on the substance, less the style, when rating a Q.

The scammer very likely has no access to your intimate ;-) data. Report him as scam and block him.

Judging by the OP's comments it's pretty clearly a rant. The poster seems to be expecting the people of this board to be justifying the law, and then shouts at them when the OP doesn't like the justification offered, complaining about being potentially scammed. Questions should be asked in a neutral fashion and people shouldn't be harangued for offering factual answers - that's definitely a mark of a rant.

I haven't shouted at anyone.  ohwilleke's detailed list of things I already knew was well-done but didn't answer the question.  They did eventually answer in a later comment.

There are many benefits from third-party access to real property records.

It allows people who work on the property and are not paid to know who the owner of the property is to give notice of a potential mechanic's lien.

It provides prospective tenants a way to confirm that the person claiming to lease property to them is authorized to do so.

It provides a way to know who is entitled to notice under various municipal laws requiring notice be given of proposed land use changes, liquor licenses, etc.

It provides a central source of property boundaries to avoid disputes, and to know who is entitled to notice or to be made a party to a lawsuit involving real property disputes.

Title companies use these records in order to confirm that someone selling or mortgaging real estate actually owns it.

Public records of sales prices of individual properties are used by appraisers to identify comparable sales which are then key to determining the price of arms-length sales of property and to determine how much money mortgage lenders are willing to lend against the property.

Someone contemplating buying real estate, or lending money against it, need to know if there are any mortgages, liens, or other encumbrances on the property.

Judgment creditors needs to know what property is owned by judgment debtors so that they can collect the debts owed to them from this property in a way that short circuits fraudulent attempts of debtors to fail to disclose all of their assets. And, people contemplating lawsuits use this information to determine if suing at all makes sense, based upon the assets of a potential lawsuit defendant.

People extending credit need to be able to verify from independent sources, the assets of someone to whom they are considering extending credit.

Utility companies need to be able to determine who is responsible for utility services provided to a parcel of real estate.

Someone injured on the property needs to know who is responsible for it.


While the information can be used by scammers, making the information public actually prevents far more scams by people who claim an interest in a parcel of real estate that they don't actually own.
In the same vein, in places with birth, death, and marriage records that are private, like my own state of Colorado, it is much easier to scam people regarding information that would get contained in these records because it can't easily be verified.
In general, privacy laws almost always lead to more fraud, not less fraud.
Incidentally, there are a number of countries in which income tax information is publicly available to everyone, with no serious ill effects. This is already the case for most public sector employees in the U.S.
Also, it is possible to own real property through an entity with publicly disclosed contact information (such as a registered agent's address) that does not publicly disclose the owners of the entity.

I am aware that the salaries of US federal employees are public records, abet not always easy to access, but are the full 1040 and 1040a tax records publicly available?

@doneal24 The 1040 tax records are not publicly available in the U.S.,  the equivalent is available in some countries.

All of the listed benefits are gained by looking up the specific property or person.  I already stated that this type of access is needed.  None of them address the actual question: How does the public benefit by alerting people (including scammers) in every state that a closing has just occurred?

@WGroleau The appraisal function requires access to everyone. And, scammers just aren't a big deal. The solution to scammers is to prosecute them, not to restrict access to information. Privacy is almost always more harmful than beneficial.

Prosecution of scammers is a good thing, but it isn't working.  And appraisals do not require notifications of sales as they occur.  At the time of appraisal, you look up properties nearby.  I still don't have justification for these notifications.

@WGroleau You weren't harmed by the scammers. Most people would see through them. And, if they didn't try to scam you this way, they'd try something else - like the fake notices of a USPS package that you needed to pick up, or extended warranty notices (I've had family members get them even if they don't have a car). Most appraisers and title companies have standing orders for notices so their databases are up to date. If the scammer is a subscriber to paid notices, the easiest thing would be to work out a way for their subscription to be terminated for use in a crime. Not hard to enforce.

I'm not sure most people would see through them.  Four of them were from the same outfit, though they used different addresses.  If "most people would see through them," then I think they'd have found more successful scheme.  Those four were attempts to sell "mortgage protection insurance" when I'm sure they KNOW that most mortgages already have PMI. All seven were designed to make the victim think they came from the mortgage company.

@WGroleau In the modern internet era, it doesn't really matter whether there's an official notification scheme or not.  If it doesn't exist, someone will write a bot that just queries every piece of property every x days and sell access to get notifications of changes.

Another reason: appraisals are not an exact science and transparency is needed to ensure tax appraisals are fair, e.g. the mayor's cousin isn't getting their property underappraised to save on taxes. This is different from income tax where there's usually little judgement involved.
